# ffmpeg how to stream video file in windows on http protocol

Tags: windows, http, ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream avideo file to localhost http stream.
my ffmpeg version details:

```
ffmpeg version N-64307-g8657612 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 29 2014 22:09:38 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-
libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsox
r --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab -
-enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
--enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-
libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 90.101 / 52. 90.101
  libavcodec     55. 68.100 / 55. 68.100
  libavformat    55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfi
le}...
```

when I use:

```
C:\Users\USER>ffmpeg -re -i myfile.mp4 -f flv udp://localhost:1234
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myfile.mp4':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.44.100
    compilation     : 0
Duration: 00:00:04.17, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 268 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 132 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
[flv @ 00000000003fc780] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to th
e muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, flv, to 'udp://localhost:1234':
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    compilation     : 0
    encoder         : Lavf55.44.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 640x48
0 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
    encoder         : Lavc55.68.100 flv
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz,
stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
    encoder         : Lavc55.68.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=      32kB time=00:00:00.44 bitrate= 591.6kbits/s
frame=   18 fps= 18 q=3.6 size=      77kB time=00:00:00.94 bitrate= 668.8kbits/s
frame=   30 fps= 20 q=8.4 size=     115kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate= 642.5kbits/s
```

its working.

but when I use http:

```
C:\Users\USER>ffmpeg -re -i myfile.mp4 -f flv http://localhost:1234
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myfile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.44.100
    compilation     : 0
  Duration: 00:00:04.17, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 268 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 132 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
http://localhost:1234: Input/output error
```

I get Input/output error.

in linux its working with ffserver.
but in windows I get this exception.

Comment: Do you have ffserver running on port 1234 on your Windows box?

Comment: There is not ffserver tool for windows.

Comment: There's you problem then. Where do you expect `ffmpeg` to send the file? There needs to be an HTTP server at the other end that's expecting the video and knows what to do with it.

Comment: But in udp output ffmpeg do not need any sever, this is happening only in http output. what is the difference?

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol, it doesn't know or care if there is anything on the other to receive the packets. There needs to be a UDP server at the other end that expects the video if you want it to do anything useful, but if there's nothing there `ffmpeg` won't know and so won't complain.

Comment: ffplay udp://localhost:1234. Plays the video just fine.

Comment: In that case `ffplay udp://localhost:1234` is acting as the server at the other end that expects the video.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different protocols (udp and http) so the outcome of the command is different.

Like Ross said in the comments : "UDP doesn't know or care if there is anything to receive the packets. If there's nothing there ffmpeg won't know and so won't complain".

FFserver is a different command to FFmpeg hence the different outputs.

Linux will behave differently according to distribution. Windows will also behave differently.

It would be easier for us to answer the question if you added a question mark  to your question with a phrase summarising what you want to know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i cant up it myself but I wish I could as it helped me.